# How to disable Asp.Net bahavior with the App_Code folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I converted a web site to a web app, and I faced the app_code folder problem :

- On my dev env, the App_Code.dll assembly is generated becasue there is code file in the App_Code folder.
- On my production env, some of my classes are not included in the assembly because in the .csproj they are marked as "Content" instead of "Compile".

So my guess is, for visual studio / .net they always create n assembly if there is a code file inside the App_Code folder, and visual studio set a class's file as "Content" when you create it inside this folder.

I know, I can rename this folder, but this would be a PITA with our source control. The other solution would be to change the file's properties when we create it, but still a PITA.

I thought that adding

```
<Compile Include="App_Code\**\*.cs"/>
```

In the app .csproj would help me but it doesn't, visual studio overrite it when I load the solution with every files in the App_Code (so the new files won't be compiled).
I'm really curious to see if there is any way to get rid of this, this can't be hard coded !